# Function Parameters with Node.js Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, blockchain

I'm using [blockexplorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blockexplorer#blockexplorerblockhash) API for blockchain, and I want to get block data based on specific hash (This hash should be taken from another function).

I'm new with using Promise, So can anyone help me to get the block data?

This is my code:

```
const be = require('blockexplorer');

be.block(be.blockIndex(0))
.then((result) => {
 console.log(result)
})
.catch((err) => {
throw err
})
```

Also, I've tried another way with using nested Promise but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `promise.then` return a promise and chain it further. Modify the code to this.

```
be.blockIndex(0)
.then((result) => be.block(result))
.then((result) => {
   console.log(result)
})
.catch((err) => {
   console.log("Error Occurred: ", err); // Don't throw the error instead handle it
});
```

Comment: It's not working, I got this error [Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 404 - "Not found"]

Comment: It's because you are catching the error and then throwing it. Always catch the error and handle it

Comment: I have modified the answer to handle the error please take a look